# Oracle XE 18c, on every connect attempt, Oracle listener OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener stops, and I am unable to connect to any connection

Tags: oracle, listener

For the purpose of learning, I have installed Oracle 18c XE v18.4.0.0 and Oracle SQL Developer v21.4.2. I have no previous experience with Oracle database.
Command **LSNRCTL stat** seems to show correct results:
[LSNRCTL stat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztDyq.png)
I am trying to connect to XEPDB1 Plugin database by using sqlplus command:
**sqlplus system/oracle@192.168.1.102:1521/XEPDB1**
(192.168.1.102 is my local IP)
but everytime I tried so, *service OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener* (and listener also) **stops**.
Then I start it again manually and try again to connect to XEPDB1 but the same thing happen again.
Respond to connection command after few minutes is: **ERROR: ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed**.
Files *listener.ora* and *tnsnames.ora* are not modified after fresh installation of Oracle 18c XE.
Much appreciate if anybody can help me.

Comment: What does the listener log file say is happening?

Comment: @AlexPoole, please find listener.log on following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13SPH-BqQC50FA-9PZIui-g2Y8MI-ycpp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of the log in your question, as formatted text. It looks like you're getting a core dump, but look at the alert log and trace files it refers to after the errors for more details, and again include the relevant parts in your question. Although this is really off-topic for this site; you might be better off asking on dba.stackexchange.com - with the relevant details included - and then deleting this. Is there a reason you've started with 18c XE rather than 21c XE? 18c is old and out of support now.

Comment: Sorry, @AlexPoole, as I said I am completely new to the Oracle database, and don't know which log items could show me what is the problem. That is why I am posting this issue to much more experienced people. Instructor ask us to install 18c XE because of easier setup than 21c XE. Beside this, versions greater than 18c are not supported on Windows 7.
Here are trace and alert logs from listener : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OwcTZq6HHCD3sRgTNr3f0z_7PS8F3bAn/view?usp=sharing
This problem is bother me for some time. Instructor also unable to help me.
Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but worth noting:  Your 'lsnrctl stat' shows the listener using port 1521, which is the default.  But the connection string you show is using port 1251.  Also please note that screen shots of command windows can be hard to read.  It is very easy to copy the text content from the cmd window, and paste it, as   code-formatted text, directly into your question.

Comment: @EdStevens You are right. It was misstyped 1251 instead of 1521. I have edited and correct my original post. Nevertheless, proper command sqlplus system/oracle@192.168.1.102:1521/XEPDB1 also stops listener service. I forgot to mention, sqlplus system/oracle command login to Oracle without any problem.

Comment: _" It was misstyped 1251"_  That's why we are so insistent about copy/paste instead of transcribe.  As for "sqlplus system/oracle" connecting with no problem ... that syntax (no network connection string) is making a direct BEQueath connection.  It is not using the listener.